# NoSQL database independent ORM/ODM for Python

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

I'm looking into the software architecture for using a NoSQL database (MongoDB). I would ideally want to use a database independent ORM/ODM for this, but I can't find any similar library to SQLAlchemy for NoSQL. Do you know any?

I do find a lot of wrappers, but nothing that seems to be database independent. If there's none, is it because all the NoSQL databases out there have different use cases that a common ORM/ODM wouldn't make sense like it does in the SQL case ?

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't exist yet because people are less likely to swap their NoSQL database?

Comment: Every relational-based DB supports some dialect of SQL that is more or less standardized.
NoSQL DBs are young, and, in the majority, dynamically changes their QL syntax. It's the main reason (as i can imagine) for developers not to work over universal ORM.

Comment: @selfnamed seems reasonable! Put in an answer and I'll give you the credit

Comment: You could look at [PyMODM](https://pymodm.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about python, but in Java you can use frameworks like PlayORM for this purpose which supports Csasandra, HBase and MongoDb.

Answer (score 0):

There are many good choices for **ODM**:

- `dataclasses` since Python 3.7 and sane since 3.10
- `msgspec` 2rd party library, focused on speed and validation
- `pandas` to handle thousands to millions of homogeneous records
- `pydantic` is a little oldschool now, but stable and robust

A successful **ORM** would be specific to a project, rather than a nosql store, as it would need to know how to express relations between documents to key prefixes. I've only done that by hand, though I imagine a framework could exist.